# Checking in storage bags for the international flights

Tags: luggage

Can I check in storage bags (duffel bag) at airport?

Japan Airline (JAL) and I'm using their aircraft 789 for my international flight between US and Japan.

I am asking about checking in storage bag as travel luggage using Japan Airline. I am not sure that they will accept the quality of storage bags at checking counter since they are not regular duffel bag materials.

Comment: Are you asking about checking a duffle bag into a storage facility at the airport , or are you asking about checking a duffle bag as hold luggage for a flight? In either case, which airport and which airline/flight?

Comment: Thank you for checking my question. I am asking about checking in storage bag as travel luggage using Japanese Airlines. I am not sure that they will accept the quality of storage bags since they are not regular duffel bag materials.

Comment: Every airline has its own policies and rules about the acceptance of hold baggage, and they can differ depending upon whether the flight is domestic or international. _Japanese Airlines_ is not an airline name. What is the specific name of the airline? Do you mean _Japan Airline (JAL)_ or a different airline? What is the itinerary of your flight(s)?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and time. Yes, Japan Airline (JAL) is a correct name and I'm using their aircraft 789 for my international flight between US and Japan.

Answer (score 5):

Check the website of your specific airline (I it's assume ANA or JAL). Most airlines will accept whatever you want to check in as long as it's within weight and size guidelines and poses no danger. For something flimsy they will waive any type of responsibility and might make you sign a waiver if you insist on checking it it at your own risk.

In general, regular duffle bags are fine for check in. But if your bag is unusual in some way, it's your problem if it gets destroyed and/or contents are lost. The airline will not take responsibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. My friend working for another airline said the same thing, it won't be an issue to check in but they won't take any responsibility.

Comment: Be aware that airport luggage systems don't like loose handles, straps, lanyards, etc. as they can get caught and block everything. Make sure you can either remove them (and put them inside the bag) or shorten them enough they can't cause issues.

Comment: Thank you for your generous assistance. That is a good point, and I will be careful for that.